# PDF conditional on two random variables being equal

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I've been revising a bit of conditional probability theory and I came across a problem I realise I don't fully understand.

Consider two random variables $X$, $Y$ with joint probability density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. What's the probability density function of $X$ given that $X=Y$?

With a condition that isn't random, we could just write
$$f_{X|Y=y}(x)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$$
In this case, since I have a random condition, I'm not sure what to do. I get the impression the answer should be in the form of
$$f_{X|Y=X}(x)=c*f_{X,Y}(x,x)$$
where $c$ is just some scaling constant that normalises the pdf. But I'm guessing this isn't the best method of doing this and I'm not sure if this is even true, so a solution to my problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If $(X, Y)$ is a two-dimensional continuous random variable with joint probability density
function $f$ and if $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are the marginal density functions of $X$ and $Y$
respectively, then the  *conditional density function  of $X$ given $Y = y$*, is denoted by
$f_{X | Y}(x | y)$, and is defined as
$$
f_{X | Y}(x | y) = \frac{f(x, y)}{f_Y(y)}, \ \ \mbox{where} \ \ f_Y(y) \neq 0
$$
for $-\infty < x < \infty$.

Comment: This does not answer OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

For most cases, the conditional event is given in the form "$Y=y$" for some constant $y$, and "$Y=X$" is not a regular condition event.

If $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$ is given, you can first calculate the marginal pdf of $X$ and $Y$, and if they are equal, then $Y=X$ is always true, which means that the conditional marginal pdf is just the initial one, i.e.,
$$
f_X(x|Y=X) = f_X(x).
$$
If you have found that they are different, then $Y=X$ is impossible, and the conditional marginal pdf will be $0$.

Comment: I think that $Y=X$ is a valid condition. In the discrete case, say for the example where $X,Y$ are i.i.d with $P(X=0)=P(Y=0)=3/4$, $P(X=1)=P(Y=1)=1/4$, then $P(X=0|X=Y)=\frac{P(X=Y=0)}{P(X=Y=0)+P(X=Y=1)}=9/10$, and $P(X=1|X=Y)=1/10$. So it seems like a valid condition and quite straightforward in the discrete case. My question is about extending this to the continuous case.

Comment: In my viewpoint, I don't believe your formulas are corrent. In your given conditons, I think $P(X=0|X=Y) = \frac{P(X=0,X=Y)}{P(X=Y)} = P(X=0) = 3/4$, and $P(X=1|X=Y) = 1/4$ by using the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: The events ${X=0}$ and ${X=Y}$ are not independent.
$\frac{P(X=0,X=Y)}{P(X=Y)}=\frac{P(X=0)*P(Y=0)}{P(X=0)*P(Y=0)+P(X=1)*P(Y=1)}=\frac{3/4*3/4}{3/4*3/4+1/4*1/4}=\frac{9}{10}$

Comment: Okay, it seems that you are right. My second consideration is that $P(X\leq x|X=Y) = \int_{\infty}^x{f_{(X,Y)}(x,x)\mathrm{d}x}$, and therefore $f_X(x|X=Y) = f_{(X,Y)}(x,x)$. This is for your reference.